# Add a layout inside the list view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I wanted to display a web view in between in the list view and bottom of the list view.
I was able to add footer to the list view to display the web view in the bottom, but I don't know how to display in the middle

Code where I have added the footer:

```
ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
WebView web;
LayoutInflater inflaterOf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout listFooterView = 
    (LinearLayout)inflaterOf.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);
web = (WebView)listFooterView.findViewById(R.id.webview_footer);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/news_footer.html");
list.addFooterView(listFooterView);
```

Please let me know how to insert the layout with web view in-between the list view

Comment: It isn't possible to add a view in the middle. You can only add a header or a footer view to a `ListView`

Comment: what are the other possibilities, if I wanted to show a layout in the middle.. create 2 list views?

Comment: What sort of data is in the `ListView`, what goes in the `WebView`? I would suggest maybe look at moving the webview if possible. Is there a reason you want it in the middle? Seems an odd place for that control to go

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom object and in your `ArrayAdapter` of `listview`, change the layout to **inflate** when getCount is equal to `list.size()/2`.

That's the way I'll handle this.

Comment: I can place the layout in the middle by using list.size()/2, but how will I shift the rest?